# C720 Function Key Configuration

Tags: keyboard, chromebook

I have eOS running great on an Acer C720 with the exception of the function keys. That model like other chromebooks uses non-standard f1-f12 settings. Does anyone have any resource for getting these keys working as they would in ChromeOS or perhaps how they're configured in GalliumOS?

Keyboard is shown below. 
http://www.laptopmag.com/images/uploads/4248/g/acer-chromebook-c720-late-2014-g14.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The automated fix as shared in below link made all the media keys work in my installation of Loki on C720.  There are a few additional fixes included, you might want to adjust the script where you find necessary.

http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/blog/automate-chromebook-fixes-for-linux/

Answer (score 0):

I a sure that is a fine script, but you can also rebind yourself under keyboard settings (layouts) in latest ubuntu mint.